# MySQL No Route to Host, mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002)

Tags: php, mysql, osx-mavericks

I am trying to install BugZilla on Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks).
I'm hitting a snag with my MySQL configuration.

I have installed MySQL from the DMG Image `mysql-5.6.14-osx10.7-x86_64`
MySQL seems to be installed and running ok.
I have created a user called bugs, and a database called bugs.
I confirm that I can login to MySql from the terminal command line, using the bugs username and password, and access the `bugs` database.

However the installation of BugZilla fails with an error connecting to MySQL. I tried a simple test and wrote this php file:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect(“localhost”,”bugs”,”********”,”bugs”);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

But it fails at line 3 with:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No route to host in /Users/bugzilla/Sites/test_my.php on line 11
>   Failed to connect to MySQL: No route to host

Why is it that I can connect from the command line, but not from php?

Comment: Change the quotes from “ to " when calling mysqli_connect

Comment: Rats! You are right. OK That solves the issue with my test file and means I've been chasing a wild goose when it comes to why my BugZilla install fails.

Comment: @user4035: Freaking "smart quotes" :-P

Comment: @Kenny try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Answer (score 1):

We experienced this error because the ip subnet used by our vagrant environment was the same as the subnet of the database server.  We needed to recreate the database server on a different subnet.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced a similar problem but through which it looks like there was a different problem case. I was getting the same error:

```
Failed to connect to the database, please check your credentials: No route to host
```

And we were able to figure out the problem was actually that the disk space of our database was full (our server administrator was out sick for a while, and we automatically make snapshots, but only manually delete them on a regular basis. After a few days, the snapshots took up the space of the entire server and rendered it unresponsive).

I don't know if this will be the answer to anyone with this issue, but if someone does stumble upon this same error, hopefully this might help.